# AppleScript using framework

Tags: frameworks, applescript

This is probably a very stupid question,

However I need to code within an App, I've been using UIbutton for a while but is not good enough, My app have a .framework files,
Can I use this for scripting ?

Example if I want a click on a button listed, is there anyway to do that?

1 button
    1 button

Answer (score 0):

The AppleScript framework is not available on iOS

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually talking about a OSX app, which have framework and .plist file, but think I gonna give up on this one anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AppleScript and System Events. Here how you can click in a menu of the application Finder.

```
tell application "Finder" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        tell menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1
            click
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I know that what I do at the moment but it's failing if the windows is in full screen or something changed, that why I thought I could use the app framework which since to have all informations listed